# libgit2 - c: how can I tell which version is being used

Tags: c, libgit2

I am writing an application that uses libgit2:

https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod

At some point I am using a value from an enum defined in types.h:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/a83fd5107879d18b31ff8173ea062136256321be/include/git2/types.h#L77

But I just noticed that in previous versions it is called GIT_OBJ_TREE:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/45c6187cbfdcfee2bcf59a1ed3a853065142f203/include/git2/types.h#L72

Tnen the queston is, how can I know what version of libgit2 is being used? I though that perhaps there is a defined value that I could use that that I cold then use something like:

```
#ifdef GIT2_0_28
// use GIT_OBJECT_TREE
#else
// use GIT_OBJ_TREE
#endif
```

But I don't see something like that. What other trick can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using stuff from https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/v0.28.0/include/git2/version.h.

In my file:

```
#if LIBGIT2_SOVERSION < 28 // old implementation
#define GIT2_OBJECT_TREE GIT_OBJ_TREE
#else // new implementation
#define GIT2_OBJECT_TREE GIT_OBJECT_TREE
#endif
```

Then in my code I use `GIT2_OBJECT_TREE`.

Will mark this as *the* answer until a better (simpler) one comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the version of libgit2, then I would not use [`LIBGIT_SOVERSION`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/a83fd5107879d18b31ff8173ea062136256321be/include/git2/version.h#L16), since that's a string that defines the "[so-version](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOVERSION.html)", which is the ABI version, not the API version.  And it's a string, which complicates that test.

I'd instead look at the major/minor/teeny version numbers which are definitely integers.

```
#if LIBGIT2_VER_MAJOR == 0 && LIBGIT2_VER_MINOR < 28
# ...
#endif
```

But in this case, I wouldn't look at the API version at all - you don't need to.

If you really want to target versions prior to 0.28 and versions later, then just use `GIT_OBJ_TREE`.  Although `GIT_OBJ_TREE` is deprecated, it's still available as part of libgit2's [safe deprecation layer](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/a83fd5107879d18b31ff8173ea062136256321be/include/git2/deprecated.h#L316) which is enabled by default.

It won't be removed until libgit2 v2.0, at the earliest.